# Why was I able to vote to close my own question (having 909 reputation only)?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I was able to succesfully vote to close [my own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189513/can-we-ignore-case-and-diacritical-marks-in-comments-what-else-we-can-change?noredirect=1#comment585378_189513), when I had just 909 rep.
[image: I can!]
[image: I did!]

I believed I need 3000 to cast close votes? Is this some kind of a feature or was it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

The [view close votes privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) allows you to vote to close your own questions at 250 reputation. To quote from the privilege page:

> This privilege allows you to view and cast close and reopen votes on your own questions.

Comment: `as long as it does not have an answer with 1 upvote`.  I don't believe that's a restriction for closing your own post.  Only deleting.

Comment: You are correct. I was thinking about deleting.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the ["View Close Vote" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) is not as clear as it should be, but if you read the description:

> ### View Close Votes
>
> Privilege Type: Moderation Privilege
> Awarded At: 250 Reputation
>
> This privilege allows you to view and cast close and reopen votes on your own questions.

The ability to view also includes the ability to vote.

Comment: I admit I just read the name and assumed details are irrelevant as it's only a view privilege. My bad.

Comment: @Mołot Until I hit that number, I was under the impression (based on the name) that it allowed you to view close votes on **any** post.  I ended up spending an hour looking for posts with close votes to test until I decided to actually read the description.

Comment: On Drupal Answers I went kinda fast to 3k border, and I had to much problems with my Drupal to bother how Stack site really works ;)